# ionic 2 issues with cordova-plugin-facebook4

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

i have this error: 
Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/ionicApp/node_modules/@ionic-native/facebook/index.d.ts, found version 4, expect

when in type :
ionic cordova run android --prod --release

I have ionic version 3.9.2

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/date-picker": "^4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/globalization": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/mixpanel": "^4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.9.1",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/video-player": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
    "cordova-android": "7.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.7",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-datepicker": "^0.9.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "~1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.11.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-mixpanel": "^4.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.3.2",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "firebase": "^5.3.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.2.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionic2-rating": "^1.2.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng-socket-io": "^0.2.4",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.4",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.10"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
    "typescript": "2.2.1"
}
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

Update all of your dependencies to the latest Angular and the right version of TypeScript

```
npm install @angular/animations@'^5.0.0' @angular/common@'^5.0.0' @angular/compiler@'^5.0.0' @angular/compiler-cli@'^5.0.0' @angular/core@'^5.0.0' @angular/forms@'^5.0.0' @angular/http@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-browser@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-server@'^5.0.0' @angular/router@'^5.0.0' typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@'^5.5.2'
```

Comment: Thank you, it fix my issue and generate another. Error: Please update @angular/cli. Angular 5+ requires at least Angular CLI 1.5+. i have uninstall my CLI and type this sudo npm install   @angular/cli. + @angular/cli@6.2.4 have been installed. by still have that error

Comment: delete the node modules and again try.